# Rename multiple columns with a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have gene expression data where the column names are  Ensembl gene names, including the version (.xx). I want to replace the column names for a few columns (ignoring the .xx) with the gene symbols. My genes of interest are in a "genes" vector, and the corresponding Ensembl names are in an "ensembl" vector.

```
df <- tibble(~"sample", ~"Ensembl1111.13", ~"Ensembl2222.1",
             "sample_A", 12, 20)
genes <- c("ACTB", "GAPDH")
ensembl <- c("Ensembl1111", "Ensembl2222")
```

I tried to use `rename_at()`, with no success. Where is the mistake in my syntax? Is there a simpler/better way?

Thanks!!

```
df_ren <- df %>%
    rename_at(vars(starts_with(ensembl)), funs(str_replace(., "/.", genes)))
```

Comment: Can you show your expected

Comment: "I want the colnames to be "sample", "ACTB"," GAPDH"

Comment: I got confused by `str_replace`, it is not needed then.  Please check my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `starts_with`, we could use `matches` as `starts_with` expects a single input, while `matches` can have multiple values if we create a single string concatened with `|` (`OR`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   rename_at(vars(matches(str_c(ensembl, collapse="|"))),
          ~genes)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  sample    ACTB GAPDH
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 sample_A    12    20
```

---

Or another option is to remove the `.` followed by the characters in the column names that starts with 'Ensembl' and use a named vector in `rename`

```
df %>% 
    rename_at(vars(starts_with("Ensembl")), ~ str_remove(., "\\..*")) %>%
    rename(!!! setNames(ensembl, genes))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  sample    ACTB GAPDH
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1 sample_A    12    20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove everything after `"."` from the names, `match` it with `ensembl` and replace it with `genes` value.

```
names(df)[match(ensembl, sub('\\..*', '', names(df)))] <- genes
#  sample    ACTB GAPDH
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1 sample_A    12    20
```